# Wordpress Custom Fields – echo only the content of the field, which is an URL

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to echo only the string of my custom field called "linkto", which is an URL. I can't find a good answer in the WordPress codex. Could you please help me?

```
<?php if (in_category( "29" )){
    echo '<a class="theid" href="';

// Here i want to echo the URL from custom field "linkto"

    echo '" target="_blank"> link</a>';

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single field go for

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your-field-name', true );
```

If there are multiple fields of the same key use

```
foreach( $values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your-field-name', false ) as $value ) {
    echo $value;
}
```

The codex is pretty clear about that. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta